# How to appear drive on windows if whole drive is selected as swap space?

Tags: swap

I was installing ubuntu at time of drive selection i selected whole drive d as swap area and then i quit the installaton now it is not appearing in windows and even in **try ubuntu** button as came up on boot please help to get back my drive so that i can see that drive in windows

Comment: in run type `diskmgmt.msc` , press enter, on identify the drive, right click format. (If format not available, delete the drive and recreate)

Comment: delete option is available how i will recreate that please help me

Comment: After deleting,  there will be a `new` option. Do you have any data on that drive that needs recovering?

Answer (score 2):

If you set up a drive as swap, you are pretty much done with the data that used to live there. That being said, you might want to look into something like this..

[Might-Just-Help](http://www.ntfs.com/partition-deleted.htm)